# How to distinguish between data drift and concept drift in data?

Tags: concept-drift, data-drift

Our team is working on a regression-like model to predict a continuous value across time. We noticed that the model performance was quite good for part of the period, while deteriorate quite a lot at the later time period. I’m guessing the data might have been drifted but not tested yet, as I’m stuck with the following questions.

i)  I guess for us to effectively resolve the drift problem, we need to distinguish whether it’s data drift or concept drift. In short, how to distinguish if it’s simply data drift, or it’s just a concept drift, or both?

ii) I’m quite confused when can we conclude data drift occurs but not concept drift, and vice versa?

iii)    What to do for remedy when we manage to know it’s caused by both data drift and concept drift?

Thank you!

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: @Dave This is from [Data Science on AWS](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1492079391/) though I'm not sure these definitions are set in stone: "Covariate shifts occur in the data distribution of model inputs (independent variables). Label shifts occur in the data distribution of model outputs (dependent variables). Concept shifts occur when the actual definition of a label changes depending on a particular feature, such as geographical location or age group." Data drift is most often used to refer to covariate shift.